# Can't change Dropdownlist.backcolor in code behind (.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist in a gridview.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_OnRowDataBound" EnableModelValidation="True" >
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Y_N">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblGetSub" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GetSub")%>' Visible = "false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_OnSelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="True" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I fire the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` I want to chage the dropdownlist.backcolor in code behind. This is my server side code.

```
protected void GridView1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;     


            ddl.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("blue");
            //ddl.Style["BackColor"] = "blue";
            //ddl.Style.Add("backcolor", "blue");
            //ddl.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("backcolor", "blue");

        }
```

I got this 4 solution in this website.

```
ddl.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("blue");
 ddl.Style["BackColor"] = "blue";
 ddl.Style.Add("backcolor", "blue");
 ddl.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("backcolor", "blue");
```

But just `ddl.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("blue");` work fine.

Can someone please tell me why the rest of 3 didn't work?

Comment: Change your parameter from `"backcolor", "blue"` to `"background-color", "blue"` for the CSS property!

Comment: It's work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the others directly set or modify the CSS style attribute of the element, and `backcolor` is not a valid CSS property - instead `background-color` is.

The first command modifies directly a property of the server-side DropdownList object. Then when the control is rendered to the browser, this affects how the .NET code creates the HTML element - this value will get translated into a valid CSS style attribute on the element which the browser can understand. You can check the rendered source code of the page via your browser's "View Source" feature to see how it gets output.

The other commands would likely work if you use the correct CSS property, here's just one for example:

```
ddl.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("background-color", "blue");
```

Comment: This help me a lot. Next time i will check the "View Source" on my browser to get the valid CSS property. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. That's a good idea. You can also check CSS documentation online of course, as well, to discover all the possibilities :-)